# Changing the path of the Telerik MVC stylesheets and javascripts

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am using the latest version of Telerik MVC with my ASP.NET MVC 3 application.  I took what was in contents and put it into another directory under:

```
root -> Assets -> telerikaspnetmvc68803
```

I don't know where to specify that the path has changed because it is still looking for the controls under ~/Content/...

Do I need to add my stylesheets like this?  Can I just add them like I would normally add them?

```
@(Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar()
   .DefaultGroup(group => group
      .Add("telerik.common.min.css")
      .Add("telerik.webblue.min.css")
      //.Combined(true)
      .Compress(true)))
```

I normally just add it like this:

If I were to register my javascripts like this then it adds a reference to a jquery file.  I don't want this reference to be added because I have a newer version that I want to use.  How do I get it to use the newer version?

```
@(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar()
   .DefaultGroup(group => group
      .Add("telerik.common.min.js")
      .Add("telerik.treeview.min.js")
      .Compress(true)))
```

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@(Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar()
   .DefaultGroup(group => group
            .DefaultPath("~/Assets/telerikaspnetmvc68803")
            .Add("telerik.common.css")
   )
)
```

Comment: Thanks this helps alot.  I have the newer jQuery file downloaded from the website.  But when registering the javascripts file as in my updated post it is also trying to add an older version of a jQuery file which I don't want.  How do I stop this?

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/web-assets-working-with-javascript-web-assets.html#jQuery